# Share a google drive, google spreadsheets API app available to any user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-console

I have made a python code that automates a process inside my work using drive and spreadsheets API , now i want to share this tool with my mates, but them does not know anything about programming, so my question is, how can I share the app to be used by any user as a third party app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged google api so i assume you are working on google sheets, if so you can create json credentials file [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for them as you did for yourself at google cloud console. Each json has email address that you can share the googlesheet with and they can access google sheet using json key and your application.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is that them does not know anything about programming i made a executable and i say them about the credentials but them does not trust on the execution of a code inside them pc or downloading credentials of them accounts, them said me that them want something like a third party application as many of those we use inside googlesheets like calendars or stuff like that. This means something in the cloud ,executed there.